# Window opener is null when opened from webview in chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webview, google-chrome-app

here is my problem:

I have a chrome application that, using webview, shows external content. In that content, there is a webpage that uses window.open and  to open new windows and those windows use window.opener to communicate back to the page.

However, if i use window.open to open a new window inside a webview, window.opener in that window is set to **null**. Is there any way to make this work?

Btw i use this hook to open webpages:

```
    webview.addEventListener('newwindow', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open(e.targetUrl)
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should read the docs next time. All you need to do is use window.attach method as shown in: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview

```
webview.addEventListener('newwindow', function(e) {
  var newWebview = document.createElement('webview');
  document.body.appendChild(newWebview);
  e.window.attach(newWebview);
});
```